# Get content from nested dictionary more effiiciently

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am iterating through nested dictionaries and fetching all values in different list. I have already created the code that does the job. But I need it to be more efficient. Does anyone know a more efficient way?

Code:

```
import collections

dict = {
    0.5: {u'Start': 0.0, u'Decision Logic#3': 5.0, u'Stop': 0.0, u'Decision Action#1': 5.0, u'Field Level DQ': 120.0},
    1.0: {u'Start': 0.0, u'Decision Logic#3': 5.0, u'Stop': 0.0, u'Decision Action#1': 5.0, u'Field Level DQ': 115.0},
    2.0: {u'Start': 0.0, u'Decision Logic#3': 5.0, u'Stop': 0.0, u'Decision Action#1': 5.0, u'Field Level DQ': 120.0},
    4.0: {u'Start': 0.0, u'Decision Logic#3': 5.0, u'Stop': 0.0, u'Decision Action#1': 5.0, u'Field Level DQ': 120.0},
    32.0: {u'Start': 3.0, u'Decision Logic#3': 5.0, u'Stop': 0.0, u'Decision Action#1': 5.0, u'Field Level DQ': 120.0},
    8.0: {u'Start': 0.0, u'Decision Logic#3': 5.0, u'Stop': 0.0, u'Decision Action#1': 5.0, u'Field Level DQ': 115.0},
    64.0: {u'Start': 2.0, u'Decision Logic#3': 5.0, u'Stop': 0.0, u'Decision Action#1': 5.0, u'Field Level DQ': 123.0},
    128.0: {u'Start': 5.0, u'Decision Logic#3': 5.0, u'Stop': 0.0, u'Decision Action#1': 5.0, u'Field Level DQ': 122.0},
    256.0: {u'Start': 3.0, u'Decision Logic#3': 5.0, u'Stop': 0.0, u'Decision Action#1': 5.0, u'Field Level DQ': 121.0},
    16.0: {u'Start': 0.0, u'Decision Logic#3': 5.0, u'Stop': 0.0, u'Decision Action#1': 5.0, u'Field Level DQ': 120.0}
    64.0: {u'Watermark': 100.0, u'Decision Action#1': 5.0, u'Stop': 0.0,
       u'Decision Logic#3': 5.0, u'Start': 5.0,
       u'Token Maskin Action#1': 425.0,
       u'Field Level DQ': 122.0}
    }

dict = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dict.items()))

list_start, decision_logic, stop, decision_action, field_dq = [], [], [], [], []

for main_key, main_val in dict.items():
    if "Start" in main_val:
        list_start.append(main_val['Start'])
    if "Decision Logic#3" in main_val:
        decision_logic.append(main_val['Decision Logic#3'])
    if "Stop" in main_val:
        stop.append(main_val['Stop'])
    if "Decision Action#1" in main_val:
        decision_action.append(main_val['Decision Action#1'])
    if "Field Level DQ" in main_val:
        field_dq.append(main_val['Field Level DQ'])

print(list_start)
print(decision_logic)
print(stop)
print(decision_action)
print(field_dq)
```

The output i want is like it should create a list automatically(generic to be precise) if i add more key in nested dictionary in this way:

```
{
    'list_start' : [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 2.0, 5.0, 3.0]
    'decision_logic' : [5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0]
    'stop' : [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    'decision_action' : [5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0]
    'field_dq' : [120.0, 115.0, 120.0, 120.0, 115.0, 120.0, 120.0, 123.0, 122.0, 121.0]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "i need to be done in more efficient way" What do you mean? What have you tried?

Comment: @bfontaine i already mention the code with output

Comment: your code is already fine, you can’t really make it more efficient. The accepted answer might be more concise but it’s 5 times less efficient.

Comment: @bfontaine i think i already got my answer. i am adding another answer in a row which i think is more efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think i modified my answer and i successfully created code in more generic way.As i said the key-value pair(like `Start`, `Decision Action`, `Stop`) of list of dictionaries can be exist or may not be and also there is a chance of adding new nested dictionaries like this so this cannot be made as static.Anyways here is the generic code :

```
dict = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dict.items()))
get_total_list = []
for i, j in dict.items():
    for item in j:
        get_total_list.append(item) if item not in get_total_list else None

print("Total Legends :", get_total_list)
main_list = {}
for item in get_total_list:
    sublist = []
    for i, j in dict.items():
        if item in j:
            sublist.append(j[item])
    main_list[item] = sublist
print(main_list)
```

---

```
# # Output:
{u'Watermark': [100.0],
 u'Decision Action#1': [5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0],
 u'Decision Logic#3': [5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0],
 u'Stop': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 u'Start': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 5.0, 5.0, 3.0],
 u'Token Maskin Action#1': [425.0],
 u'Field Level DQ': [120.0, 115.0, 120.0, 120.0, 115.0, 120.0, 120.0, 122.0,
                     122.0, 121.0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use List Comprehension:

```
import collections
dict1 = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dict.items()))

list_start  = [j['Start'] for i,j in dict1.items()]
decision_logic = [j['Decision Logic#3'] for i,j in dict1.items()]
stop = [j['Stop'] for i,j in dict1.items()]
decision_action = [j['Decision Action#1'] for i,j in dict1.items()]
field_dq = [j['Field Level DQ'] for i,j in dict1.items()]

# Output
# list start = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 2.0, 5.0, 3.0]
# decision_logic = [5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0]
# stop = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
# decision_action = [5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0]
# field_dq = [120.0, 115.0, 120.0, 120.0, 115.0, 120.0, 120.0, 123.0, 122.0, 121.0]
```

Comment: Can you do it more generic way. like i can also have more keys like `start`, `stop`, `Decision Action#1` . i need to generate list dynamically

Comment: OP asked for a more efficient way. This code is 5 times *less* efficient because it loops 5 times over the dictionnary instead of only once.

Comment: @bfontaine is correct. please make more efficient. its looping 5 times. if i add 10 more key-value pair in nested dictionary, it will loop 10 times. therefore its not efficient. please give another approach.